# Couldn't find ProjectSite without an ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two models - `ProjectSite` and `Project`.

I uploaded a file in project_sites table, now I want to access that file in  `projects#index`. But I'm getting an error

```
Couldn't find ProjectSite without an ID
```

There is one to many association between Project and ProjectSite.

projects_controller.rb

```
  before_action :find_project_sites?

    def find_project_sites?
      @project_sites = ProjectSite.find(params[:project_site_id])
    end
```

in controller view

```
<% @project_sites.each do |project_site| %>
<% end %>
```

here is schema.rb

```
  create_table "project_sites", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "attendance"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.integer "project_id"
    t.index ["project_id"], name: "index_project_sites_on_project_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_project_sites_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "project_name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.integer "user_id"
  end
```

routes.rb

```
resources :project_sites
resources :projects
devise_for :users
```

project.rb  (model)

```
has_many :projects
has_many :project_sites
```

Comment: Don't use question mark in the end of method name that returns a record. By ruby convention methods with `?` at the end (predicate methods) should return boolean value (true/false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When resolving action `project#index` your params are empty, so `params[:project_site_id]` will be obviously `nil`, as you're operating on collection, not a single object.

I'm still not sure what you're trying to reach, but I guess you're trying to set up `has_many` association on `Project` model with `ProjectSite`.
After proper setting up association in models, in `#index` you can reach `project_sites` for each of indexed projects:

```
Project.all.each do |project|
  project.project_sites
end
```

On member actions (`#show`, `#create`, `#edit`, `#update` etc.) you need to set up  project

```
@project = Project.find(:id)
```

It might be done in `:befor_action` but restricted to `only: [:show, :edit, :create, :update, :destroy]`. Next you can get associated sites by `@project.project_sites`